# how to distribute before transform in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

In hive, I want to distribute table by one column and do transform using python for each distributed part.

## For example:

I want to the operation to the record with a specific column D number like this:

```
from
    (select *
    from raw_table
    where D=12345
    sort by A)
    sb
insert overwrite table u_12345
partition (X,Y)
select transform(cast(A as double),B,C,D,E,F,X,Y)
using 'hello.py'
as A,B,C,D,E,F,X,Y
;
```

Now I want to do it for all different column D numbers, I wrote the code like:

```
from raw_table
insert overwrite table clean_data
partition (X,Y)
select transform(cast(A as double),B,C,D,E,F,X,Y)
using 'hello.py'
as A,B,C,D,E,F,X,Y
distribute by D
;
```

But it doesn't works the way I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a distribution sub query :

I haven't tested this one :

```
From (select A,B,C,D,E,F,X,Y from raw_table distribute by D)
insert overwrite table clean_data
partition (X,Y)
select transform(cast(A as double),B,C,D,E,F,X,Y)
using 'hello.py'
as A,B,C,D,E,F,X,Y ;
```

Working on my cluster :

```
create table clean-data as 
select 
transform (key, B,C,D,E,F,G) 
USING 'reducer_script.py' as (key, B,C,D,E,F,G_reduced)
from (key, B,C,D,E,F,G from raw_table distribute by KEY sort by KEY, D ) alias ;
```